# Using GAS batchUpdate to copy data from specific cells on a Google Sheets Custom form to a specific row on a different sheet in the same Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm floundering again. The last question regarded a speed-up for writing values from a spreadsheet:sheet row to specific cells on a custom form (derived from a sheet).
This time, I'm trying to do the reverse...Copy data from the list of cells on the form to a specific row on the datasheet. The statements to 'push' data to the array work. Then, I get an error when I run the batchUpdate code (below) that I cannot figure out. Any help would be appreciated.
...OR should I just revert to item-by-item copying from the array to the datasheet (~5seconds)?

"Error
GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate failed with error: Invalid value at 'data[0]' (type.googleapis.com/google.apps.sheets.v4.ValueRange), "5693123-Q5aa"
Invalid value at 'data[1]' (type.googleapis.com/google.apps.sheets.v4.ValueRange), "Fredi"
Invalid value at 'data[2]' (type.googleapis.com/google.apps.sheets.v4.ValueRange), "Yeast"
...followed by another 53 lines of similar messages for each data cell."`enter code here`

```js
//** Function to copy data from the specific cells of the User form ("User Contact Info Form") to the spreadsheet sheet ("VolunteerListTbl") into Row# (DatabaseRow2Update) */
function Ex_UpdateRecord(){

  var Ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ShUserForm=Ss.getSheetByName("User Contact Info Form");
  var DataSheet = Ss.getSheetByName("VolunteerListTbl");
  var DatabaseRow2Update = ShUserForm.getRange("A11").getValue();
  var LastColNumber = DataSheet.getLastColumn(); 

  var RangesToUpdate = ["C11", "F10", "B10", "B14", "B16", "B12", "C17", "F14", "F15", "I10", "I12", "I14", "I16", "F17", "B19", "F20", "I20", "F22", "I22", "F24", "C27", "B22", "C23", "B24", "B26", "F28", "C29", "B28", "B34", "B32", "G32", "G36", "C36", "B40", "B42", "E40", "H40", "E42", "H42", "B44", "E44", "H44", "E46", "H46", "C48", "B52", "B54", "F52", "B56", "F54", "F56", "F11", "C17",  "D19", "D20"]; //List of cells containing data to be updated on the "VolunteerListTbl" sheet

  //Routine to create the array of values to be used to update the sheet's row values
  var FormValuesArray = [];
  for (var j=0; j<RangesToUpdate.length; j++){ //this loop will add each successive value for the cells listed above...to fill the array (1x56 values)
    FormValuesArray.push(ShUserForm.getRange(RangesToUpdate[j]).getValue());
    
    Logger.log("Array value for j= " + j + "; is " + ShUserForm.getRange(RangesToUpdate[j]).getValue() + " for the range " + RangesToUpdate[j])
  }
  
  DataSheet.getRange(DatabaseRow2Update,1,1,LastColNumber).activate();//Added this to specify the row where the data was to be updated
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate({data: FormValuesArray, valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED"}, Ss.getId());

  return  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to copy the values from the range of `RangesToUpdate` in the sheet "User Contact Info Form" to the same range in the sheet "VolunteerListTbl".
- You want to achieve this using Sheets API.

When I saw your script, `FormValuesArray.push(ShUserForm.getRange(RangesToUpdate[j]).getValue());` is used in a loop. In this case, the process cost becomes high. For this, I would like to propose retrieving the values using Sheets API.

And, about your this script `Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate({data: FormValuesArray, valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED"}, Ss.getId());`, it seems that `FormValuesArray` is an array like `["value1", "value2",,,]`. The request body of the method of spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate is `{"data": [{"range": "", "values": []}]}`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate) I thought that this might be the reason of your issue. In your request body, it is required to set the range and values properties.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function Ex_UpdateRecord() {
  var Ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssId = Ss.getId();
  var srcSheetName = "User Contact Info Form";
  var dstSheetName = "VolunteerListTbl";
  var RangesToUpdate = ["C11", "F10", "B10", "B14", "B16", "B12", "C17", "F14", "F15", "I10", "I12", "I14", "I16", "F17", "B19", "F20", "I20", "F22", "I22", "F24", "C27", "B22", "C23", "B24", "B26", "F28", "C29", "B28", "B34", "B32", "G32", "G36", "C36", "B40", "B42", "E40", "H40", "E42", "H42", "B44", "E44", "H44", "E46", "H46", "C48", "B52", "B54", "F52", "B56", "F54", "F56", "F11", "C17", "D19", "D20"];

  // Retrieve values from "dstSheetName".
  var values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchGet(ssId, { ranges: RangesToUpdate.map(e => `'${srcSheetName}'!${e}`) });
  
  // Create a request body.
  var FormValuesArray = values.valueRanges.map((e, i) => ({ range: `'${dstSheetName}'!${RangesToUpdate[i]}`, values: e.values }));

  // Put the values to "VolunteerListTbl".
  Ss.getSheetByName(dstSheetName).getRange(DatabaseRow2Update, 1, 1, LastColNumber).activate();
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate({ data: FormValuesArray, valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" }, ssId);
}
```

- In this modified script, the range of `RangesToUpdate` in "User Contact Info Form" sheet is copied to the same range of `RangesToUpdate` in "VolunteerListTbl" sheet.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate)

### Added 1:

From your following replying,

> The number of data fields from the source (the "User Contact Info Form") and the destination are the same. It is the locations on the sheets that differ. For example, cell C11 on the form copies to column 1 on the destination sheet ("VolunteerListTbl") and cell F10 on the form copies to column 2 on "VolunteerListTbl"... and so on. The arrangement on the form was due to groupings that allowed a cohesive display. The RangesToUpdate (source) are in the same order as the cells on the destination table. Thanks for making the effort to clarify.

I thought that you wanted to put the values to a row in the sheet "VolunteerListTbl". In this case, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

```js
function Ex_UpdateRecord() {
  var Ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssId = Ss.getId();
  var srcSheetName = "User Contact Info Form";
  var dstSheetName = "VolunteerListTbl";
  var RangesToUpdate = ["C11", "F10", "B10", "B14", "B16", "B12", "C17", "F14", "F15", "I10", "I12", "I14", "I16", "F17", "B19", "F20", "I20", "F22", "I22", "F24", "C27", "B22", "C23", "B24", "B26", "F28", "C29", "B28", "B34", "B32", "G32", "G36", "C36", "B40", "B42", "E40", "H40", "E42", "H42", "B44", "E44", "H44", "E46", "H46", "C48", "B52", "B54", "F52", "B56", "F54", "F56", "F11", "C17", "D19", "D20"];

  // Retrieve values from "dstSheetName".
  var values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchGet(ssId, { ranges: RangesToUpdate.map(e => `'${srcSheetName}'!${e}`) });
  
  // Create an array for putting to spreadsheet.
  var FormValuesArray = values.valueRanges.map(e => e.values[0][0]);

  // Put the values to "VolunteerListTbl".
  var dstSheet = Ss.getSheetByName(dstSheetName);
  dstSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, FormValuesArray.length).setValues([FormValuesArray]);
  // or dstSheet.appendRow(FormValuesArray);
}
```

- In this script, the retrieved values from `User Contact Info Form` is put to a row of the sheet `VolunteerListTbl`.
- In this case, the values are put using `setValues` and `appendRow`.
- When you want to append the row to the destination sheet, please use `dstSheet.appendRow(FormValuesArray)`.

### Added 2:

When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, I noticed that your destination sheet name is `VolSearchResult Tbl`. But your script uses `VolunteerListTbl`. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue. And, I tested my sample script reflecting the modification suggested in my comment, I confiemed no error occurs. For this, please test the following script.

#### Sample script:

```js
function Ex_UpdateRecord() {
  var Ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssId = Ss.getId();
  var srcSheetName = "User Contact Info Form";
  var dstSheetName = "VolSearchResult Tbl";
  var RangesToUpdate = ["C11", "F10", "B10", "B14", "B16", "B12", "C17", "F14", "F15", "I10", "I12", "I14", "I16", "F17", "B19", "F20", "I20", "F22", "I22", "F24", "C27", "B22", "C23", "B24", "B26", "F28", "C29", "B28", "B34", "B32", "G32", "G36", "C36", "B40", "B42", "E40", "H40", "E42", "H42", "B44", "E44", "H44", "E46", "H46", "C48", "B52", "B54", "F52", "B56", "F54", "F56", "F11", "C17", "D19", "D20"];

  // Retrieve values from "dstSheetName".
  var values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchGet(ssId, { ranges: RangesToUpdate.map(e => `'${srcSheetName}'!${e}`) });
  
  // Create an array for putting to spreadsheet.
  var FormValuesArray = values.valueRanges.map(e => e.values && e.values[0] ? e.values[0][0] : ""); // This modification is from my comment.

  // Put the values to "VolSearchResult Tbl".
  var dstSheet = Ss.getSheetByName(dstSheetName);
  dstSheet.appendRow(FormValuesArray);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I may have been unclear in my statements. Your interpretation "You want to copy the values from the range of RangesToUpdate in the sheet "User Contact Info Form" to the same range in the sheet "VolunteerListTbl"."  Those ranges are not the same (the form ranges are different from the destination ranges in the "VolunteerListTbl").  Not sure if that makes a difference in your suggestion. I'll tryout the batchUpdate suggestion.

Comment: @Charles Gray Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. I imagined the destination range from your script. Because the range was unclear for me. About `Those ranges are not the same (the form ranges are different from the destination ranges in the "VolunteerListTbl").`, in that case, can I ask you about the destination range? Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot understand it. I apologize for this. By the way, the range of `RangesToUpdate` is the source range. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: The number of data fields from the source (the "User Contact Info Form") and the destination are the same. It is the locations on the sheets that differ. For example, cell C11 on the form copies to column 1 on the destination sheet ("VolunteerListTbl") and cell  F10 on the form copies to column 2 on "VolunteerListTbl"... and so on. The arrangement on the form was due to groupings that allowed a cohesive display. The  RangesToUpdate (source) are in the same order as the cells on the destination table. Thanks for making the effort to clarify.

Comment: @Charles Gray Thank you for replying. From your replying, I added one more modified script. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for both solutions. I'll grind through them and let you (and the rest of the world) know what worked best and the processing time savings. I am extremely grateful for your efforts.

Comment: Option #1 cut time to ~2sec (from ~5sec).

 Ss....getRange(DatabaseRow2Update, 1, 1, LastColNumber).activate(); // Substituted the destination row

The ...batchUpdate({... ran, but copied data to random cells in the datasheet (none correct). Goal: update source data cells (including "", blank, or Null cells).

#2: The 2nd mod choked on: 'var FormValuesArray = values.valueRanges.map(e => e.values[0][0]);'

Error -- "Type Error: Cannot read property '0' of Undefined"

Should e.values[0][0] include a variable? 
Thanks again for any help.

Comment: @Charles Gray Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. Can I ask you about the detail of it? And by the way, what is `Option #1` and `Option #2`?

Comment: Actually NOT solved. I had to cut some explanations due to message length. Option#1 is the first set of Modified Script you offered. Option#2 is the Second set of Modified Script. Neither worked. #1 cut execution time, but copied the data into random cells (NOT where it should have been copied). 
The Second (#2) displayed an error (see previous note). Perhaps the 'FormValuesArray= ' statement needs a variable in place of the one of the [0][0] (in  valueRanges.map(e => e.values[0][0]);)?

Comment: @Charles Gray Thank you for replying. About `Option #1` and `Option #2`, I could understand them. About `Option #1`, from your 1st replying, I understood that you wanted to put the values to the 1 row. So I proposed `Option #2`. In this case, I think that your goal achieve with it. About your current issue, for example, when `var FormValuesArray = values.valueRanges.map(e => e.values[0][0]);` is modified to `var FormValuesArray = values.valueRanges.map(e => e.values && e.values[0] ? e.values[0][0] : "");`, what result will you obtain?

Comment: @Charles Gray If the above modification was not the direct solution, in order to correctly understand your current situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating the issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237686/discussion-between-charles-gray-and-tanaike).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestions from Tanaike, a solution was developed that reduced the execution time from ~1300ms down to ~400-600ms. The code that worked (adapted to my application for copying revised data to 2 different tables in Google Apps Script) are shown in the lines of code. The last two lines can be interchanged, with the first being used for updating an existing record and the second (using the 'append' method) is for adding a new record.

```js
  var srcSheetName = "User Contact Info Form";// 'Source' sheet name
  var dstSheetName = "Volunteer List Tbl"; // 'Destination' sheet name was "VolunteerListTbl";
  var dstSheet2Name = "VolSearchResult Tbl"; // 'Destination' sheet name was "VolunteerListTbl";

// Retrieve values from "srcSheetName" (source)
  var values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchGet(ssId, { ranges: FormRangesToCopy.map(e => `'${srcSheetName}'!${e}`) });

// Create an array for putting to spreadsheet. /// Method 2
  var FormValuesArray = values.valueRanges.map(e => e.values && e.values[0] ? e.values[0][0] : ""); // This modification is from my comment.

// Copy the values to "Volunteer List Tbl".
  var dstSheet = Ss.getSheetByName(dstSheetName);
  var dstSheet2 = Ss.getSheetByName(dstSheet2Name);
  dstSheet.getRange(DataSheetRowDisplayed,1,1,FormValuesArray.length).setValues([FormValuesArray]); //Worked!!!
  dstSheet2.getRange(SearchRowDisplayed,1,1,FormValuesArray.length).setValues([FormValuesArray]); //Worked!!!

// OR Append a new record to table  
//a  dstSheet.appendRow(FormValuesArray); //Append Row adds a 'New' row.
```